# Input to step functions is wrapped in an array

Tags: aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

I am passing input from eventbridge pipes to step functions. The output of the transformer (to target step functions) in pipes looks fine:

```
{
  "meta-data": {
    "id": "123"
  }
  "body": {
    "first": "1",
    "second": "2"
  }
}
```

But the input received from pipes into the step functions is wrapped in an array:

```
[{
  "meta-data": {
    "id": "123"
  }
  "body": {
    "first": "1",
    "second": "2"
  }
}]
```

How do I extract the input inside of the array input in step functions:

I tried extracting from the context object using `"$": "$"` in a pass state but I this syntax does not seem to be right.

Comment: The two code blocks are identical.  Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your question has a typo and you meant that your [Step Functions Workflow](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) receives the following:

```
[
  {
    "meta-data": {
      "id": "123"
    }
    "body": {
      "first": "1",
      "second": "2"
    }
  }
]
```

In this case, you probably want to set [`InputPath`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-inputpath) in your first state to be `$[0]` which will then pick the first element in the array of items passed as input.

But be careful you are sure your [Pipe](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/pipes/) will only ever send a single element in that array as input to your . If there could be more than one, then you probably want to use a [Map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) state.