# AWS State Machine Execution Input is an array

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

How do I force a the input of a state machine to be an object not an array?

I have a queue which contains jobs where the payload looks like

```
{ "domain": "stackoverflow.com" }
```

Using EventBridge Pipes I have a Pipe where the source is the queue and the target is a Step Function State Machine. The state machine receives each job from the queue as expected. Left with the default settings, the Step Function receives

```
{ "body": "{\"domain\": \"stackoverflow.com\"}", ... }
```

When setting the Pipe Target Input Transformer to

```
{ "domain": "<$.body.domain>" }
// <$.body> causes execution error despite showing the correct output in the tester in the pipes UI
```

The Step function receives

```
[ { "domain": "stackoverflow.com" } ]
```

Herein lies my question.

How do I prevent a step function receiving an array as input? (Why is it an array in the first place?)

I suppose the additional notes/context for this is

- Use of execution input throughout state machine - There are many nested steps throughout the state machine, almost all  of which require the original input. If it's in the wrong format, I either rely on using `"InputPath": "$.[0]"` on every step in the state or pass the domain down between each function. InputPath isn't the worst option as I'll likely have to use it anyway.
- Readability/understanding - It means additional code in my lambda where I have to accept/handle an array of input which makes no logical sense given there's a single object required and will never be multiple items.
- Console testing - moot probably as this doesn't matter often, but while testing I'm manually triggering the state machine from the console with some test data. Twice already I've sent {} instead of [] because my brain is wired that the function expects a single object input.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75729996 in case it helps.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. That solution is the same result as described in my additional notes so unfortunately doesn't help. I suppose it does indicate that it may not be possible given the suggested solution

Comment: Agree, it seems that way. Does it being an array cause a major issue or is it just an annoyance? If I find out any more, I'll update.

Comment: It causes confusion and overhead within my state machine definition as every state which needs it needs to flatten it, but i think it also causes a problem (albeit possibly my error). For example, If i use `"ResultPath": "$.output"` to combine the original input with the output of a step, I get `Unable to apply step "output" to input` obviously because its trying to create a property on an array, but i can use `$[0].output` and then it's `[{domain: x, output: { ... }}]` which works but still means every step needs to grab [0] etc.

Comment: Add a `Pass` state at the start of the state machine with `InputPath` set to `$[0]`.

Comment: @Marcelotsvaz this has the same effect as having `InputPath` set to `$[0]` on the first step of my state machine, regardless of it being a Pass or Task. It doesn't solve the issue of accessing it later in the state machine as `$$.Execution.Input` for example would return [{...}] again and need further cleanup. As it stands I have many Pass steps combining using `JsonMerge($, $$.ExecutionInput[0], false)` and  `Parameters: { 'domain.$': '$$.Execution.Input[0].domain' }` all over my state machine when i need the domain

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem for `$$.Execution.Input` but it does for `$`. The difference from a `Task` state is that in a `Pass` state the parameters become the output of the state, allowing you to propagate the change made with `InputPath` (if you use the default `ResultPath` that discards the input).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. perhaps if you could post an answer that'd help? As it stands i'm passing `InputPath: $[0]` into a `Task` at step 1 which gives me the value fine for use in step 1. If i use a `Pass` state, as step 1 with `$[0]` the output of step 1 is now without array, and the input to step 2 (my Task which was at step1). In both cases, my step be it step 1 or step 2 receives `{domain: '...'}` instead of `[{domain: '...'}]`?